# How can I get string from recources file in not activity or fragment class

Tags: java, android, string, resources, android-recyclerview

I've got strings in strings.xml for example:

```
 <string name="movietitleeng_goodfellas">Goodfellas</string>
    <string name="movietitleeng_casino">Casino</string>
    <string name="movietitleeng_infiltration">Infiltration</string>
```

and now I want if I click on recyclerView item then show me info about this film (only for exercise).

recyclerView's onItemClick method:

```
 public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
                    Movie movie = movieArrayList.get(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), movie.getInfo(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

and method from Movie class:

```
public int getTitle() {
    return title;
}   
public String getInfo(){
    String titleS = getResources().getString(getTitle());
    return titleS;
}
```

Movie class extends Context. It is required to use getRecources() method.

and when I click one of recyclerView item, application crash with a lot of statements:

```
08-21 15:25:39.823 18627-18627/com.example.android.mbm I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
08-21 15:25:42.613 18627-18627/com.example.android.mbm E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.
08-21 15:25:42.613 18627-18627/com.example.android.mbm E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback08-21 15:25:42.616 18627-18627/com.example.android.mbm E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.res.Resources.getString(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at com.example.android.mbm.model.Movie.getInfo(Movie.java:103)
                                                                           at com.example.android.mbm.fragments.MovieFragment$1.onItemClick(MovieFragment.java:44)
                                                                           at com.example.android.mbm.fragments.MovieFragment$RecyclerItemClickListener.onInterceptTouchEvent(MovieFragment.java:117)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchOnItemTouch(RecyclerView.java:2261)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(RecyclerView.java:2389)
                                                                           at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:9390)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2549)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2240)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2555)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2254)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2461)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1777)
                                                                           at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2865)
                                                                           at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:60)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2422)
                                                                           at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:9610)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4436)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4302)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3836)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3889)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3855)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3981)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4038)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3836)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3889)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3855)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3863)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3836)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6135)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6109)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6070)
                                                                           at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6251)
                                                                           at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
                                                                           at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
                                                                           at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:330)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller
08-21 15:25:42.649 18627-18627/com.example.android.mbm I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18627 SIG: 9
```

Comment: and yes, I was looking for answer in other topics but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You should pass Context to Movie.class. It can't extend Context class.

Comment: when I make a new variable in fragment class: 
Context context = getContext(); 
and pass it to Movie constructor and then use it in Movie class: 
context.getResources().getString(title) my application crash at the very beginning of action without clicking anything.

Comment: What is a reason? LogCat